# Parser exception for C\:...\AndroidManifest.xml: The markup in the document preceding the root element must be well-formed

Tags: android

What have I looked over in the code that is causing this error. Don't see anything wrong with it. What's the issue?

There is also an R cannot be resolved t a variable error in each java file in the project. Does that have anything to do with this?

Here's the manifest file.

```
<<<<<<< Original
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.activity2"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.authorwjf.youtubeapi.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_activity2" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name= ".Search" >
                        <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
                        </intent-filter>
                <meta-data android:name="android.app.searchable"
                           android:resource="@xml/searchable"/>       
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".OtherActivity" >
        <!-- enable the search dialog to send searches to SearchableActivity -->
        <meta-data android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
                   android:value=".SearchableActivity" />
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>

=======
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <application>
        <activity android:name="com.example.activity2.OtherActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_other"
            >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
>>>>>>> Added
```

Comment: first line has VCS artifacts in it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first line is `<<<<<<< Original`

And you have a section at the end preceeded by `=======` - it appears you had a merge conflict that was not resolved. Remove those lines and merge the two `<manifest>` elements together so get a single, correct manifest.